# About field "customerConsented" in ConsumptionRequest when handle CONSUMPTION_REQUEST notification in iOS app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/customerconsented
From Apple's document, it says "A Boolean value that indicates whether the customer consented to provide consumption data to the App Store."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/send_consumption_information
And from this one: "If the customer provided consent, respond by calling this API and sending the consumption data in the ConsumptionRequest to the App Store. If not, don’t respond to the CONSUMPTION_REQUEST notification."

But how do we know the customer agrees to provide consumption data or not? How do we ask him, or just pass true for this value?
Please help me, I searched everything I could, include videos from WWDC2021 but I still can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

This WWDC21 video explains it a bit:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10175

Timecode: 20:10

[The way I understand it is] you basically display a dialogue BEFORE you initiate the `StoreKit.Transaction.beginRefundRequest`. This dialogue **has to** display what data will be provided to Apple.

In addition you can either just provide an "ok" button (implicit approval), or provide a checkbox that you have to check or uncheck (explicit, required in certain jurisdictions, legally stronger).

You need to save that checkbox value for when the `CONSUMPTION_REQUEST` hits your server.

If the consumer does not consent or makes the refund request outside your app and not via `StoreKit.Transaction.beginRefundRequest` you have to ignore the `CONSUMPTION_REQUEST`. Apple will only use the supplied data if `customerConsented` is `true`.

**Edit:** It might also be possible to just add the implied consent for data sharing in case of a refund to your privacy rules and terms & conditions. But I am no lawyer.